# Given $f(x)=αe^{x-1}+β\ln x-1$ show that $α=1, β=-1$ and more

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

> Given $f(x)=αe^{x-1}+β\ln x-1$ at which the $C_f$ is tangential to the axis $x'x$ at the point $A(1,0)$.
>
> **I)** Show that $α=1$ and $β=-1$.
>
> **II)** Find the monotony of $f$ and then, show that $f(x) \ge0, \forall x>0.$
>
> **III)** Find the surface area which is enclosed by the the graph of $g(x)=xf(x), x>0$, the axis $x'x$ and the straight line $x=2.$
>
> **IV)** Show that $$f'(x)>{f(x)\over x+1}, \forall x>1.$$

**Personal work:**

**I)** Given the point $A(1,0)$ we know that $f(1)=0$...

**II)** Since $α=1$ and $\beta =-1$, then $f(x)=e^{x-1}-lnx-1, x>0$

For $x>0: f'(x)=\cdots=e^{x-1}-{1\over x}$

$$f'(x)=0 \iff e^{x-1}-{1\over x}=0 \iff e^{x-1}={1\over x}\iff _{x\neq 0} xe^{x-1}=1 \iff x=1$$

$$f'(x)>0\iff\cdots \iff xe^{x-1}>1 \iff x>1$$
Therefore $f$ is strictly increasing at $(0,+\infty).$

**III)** $$g(x)=xe^{x-1}-xlnx-x, x>0$$

$$\int_1^2|g(x)| dx=\int_1^2 g(x) dx=\int_1^2 {(xe^{x-1}-xlnx-x)} dx=\cdots$$

**IV)** This is the one that I'm struggling the most. Should I multiply both sides with $x+1$, where $x>1$, and then reach to an inequality that is true based upon the previous questions?

Comment: Why not substitute the values of the parameters , find $f’$ and then consider a new function and study it for its monotony ?

Comment: @Tolaso If you're referring to question **II)** I've already substituted $α$ and $β$ so $f$ has got its "final form".

Comment: No I’m referring to your last question !!

Comment: I have to admit I fail to see why you are only restricting your analysis to $x>1$ in many cases, and $x>0$ in others...

Comment: @Martigan For example, $g(x)$ is defined at $\mathbb R^*_+$

Comment: @Tolaso let me try your suggestion

Comment: @AlexanderVoliotis Question III, you take the integral between 1 and 2, which is not giving the correct surface area... $g(x)$ could be easily extended to $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

We already know

$$f(x)=e^{x-1}-\ln x -1$$

so
$$f'(x)=e^{x-1}- x^ {-1}$$

Let me denote $$k(x):=\frac{f(x)}{x+1}$$

We know that $k(1)=\frac{f(1)}2=0$ and $f'(1)=0$.

Now we consider $$h(x):=f'(x)-k(x)$$

Notice that

$$h'(x)=f''(x)-\frac{f'(x)}{x+1}+\frac{f(x)}{(x+1)^2}\\=e^{x-1}+\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{e^{x-1}}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x(x+1)}+\frac{f(x)}{(x+1)^2}\\
=e^{x-1}\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x(x+1)}+\frac{f(x)}{(x+1)^2}
>0$$
since $e^{x-1},x,x+1,x^2,f(x)>0$ for $x>1>0$

Since $h(1)=0$ and $h'(x)>0$ for $x>1$, 
$$h(x)=f'(x)-\frac{f(x)}{x+1}>0$$ for $x>1$ which implies
$$f'(x)>\frac{f(x)}{x+1}$$ for all $x>1$.

Comment: Yep , that’s exactly what I suggested !! Good work !